# Why can't I directly assign to element.style in Chrome using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Quick question... for some reason, when I run the following in Chrome (or Safari) on my "li" tags:

```
myListElement.style.backgroundColor="red";
```

It works. Yet when I try the following:

```
myListElement.style="li{background:red;}";
```

It doesn't. However, it works in Firefox. Does anyone know why this is? I've resorted to using the latter method because when I do the first method it overrides the :hover styling I have assigned to my elements. Otherwise, I'd be using the first method. Any help is appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: which the FF version used... doesn't seems to be working for me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/K9Sn3/3/

Comment: The solution you are looking for might be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/K9Sn3/4/ - if you click on the li the red background will appear still if you hover the hover background will appear

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the `style` attribute associated with DOM elements, you'll see that, at least in Chrome, it's actually a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object -- which is why changing it to a string doesn't work. One of *its* attributes is `backgroundColor`, and *that* is a string which you can simply modify. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
myListElement.setAttribute("style", "background:red;");
```

Comment: it is the same as `myListElement.style.backgroundColor="red";` because both are setting the inline style attribute

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yeah, you're absolutely right, I though he's looking for something more verbose (calling the css as is), perhaps I misunderstood

Comment: I should mention I'm trying to accomplish this via pure javascript.. no jQuery.

Comment: @Nickersoft we'll there is no jquery in what I've written

Comment: I'm sorry... I commented on the wrong answer. I was referring to the above JSFiddle, which included jQuery. My bad!